# How to find Cell that contains a Range in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word VBA I have a reference to a Range that is contained withing a table cell.

How can I get a reference to the containing cell (the innermost cell if there are nested tables)?

What I'm trying to achieve is to find the cell containing my range, then move to the next adjacent cell.

Comment: `Debug.Print rng.Cells(1).Next.Range.Text`

Comment: Thanks.  I thought rng.Cells referenced cells that were entirely contained within rng.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Debug.Print rng.Cells(1).Next.Range.Text
```

Comment: + 1 Glad the query is solved but I am kind of finding it hard to understand what the user wants. What I am trying to imagine is two 2D tables with 2 Rows/Columns each inside another (1 cell) 1D table. LEt's say the user has a reference to the 1 Cell (1D table) `Set rng = tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range` So what is the user trying to do now? Get the innermost cell from the 1st 2D table or the 2nd 2D table? Or I am seeing this completely the wrong way?

Comment: I took it to mean the Joe has a range and wants to go "up" from that range to the first table cell and then get a reference to the next cell over in the row containing that cell.